# Limiting current on demand

Tags: usb, current-limiting

I’m reimplementing a certain proprietary USB cable. The other end of the cable among GND, VCC and data lines also features ID line

I implemented that identification protocol on a FPGA, but according to what I sniffed from the original cable, after handling one of the requests from master on ID line, the cable turns off VCC line for like 20 ms, then turns it on again. While this little gap, I believe, it switches to a full available current, because as far as I could investigate, this cable only allows 10-15 mA in an idle state (with 5V still though)

So to complete my task, I have to implement the same mechanism - being able to switch current on VCC line from 10 mA to full current USB can provide (so up to 2-3 A) on demand from FPGA/MCU

What would be the easiest solution for this?

Comment: "I implemented that identification protocol on" - which protocol you are talking about?

Comment: Very similar to 1-Wire, but not really 1-Wire – a proprietary thing

Answer (score 1):

In USB, there's two current limits to consider:

- Downstream-facing limit
- Upstream draw

The downstream limit varies depending on whether you are a host or hub, and whether you're a battery charger or not.

- Bus-powered hub downstream: 100mA
- Self-powered or host downstream, USB2: 500mA
- Self-powered or host downstream, USB3: 900mA
- Battery charger, USB 2 or 3: up to 2.1 or 2.4A

When you attach a device, it is supposed to sense, then obey the limits set by the upstream port. For a device that has a USB endpoint, this is done as a protocol. For battery charging, the endpoint looks at the D+/D- voltage to determine how much current it is allowed to draw.

More about that sensing here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4803.html

The takeaway is, unless you're a hub, you don't need to limit the downstream current other than what USB specifies. It is up to the *device* to self-limit its current.

Comment: It’s not really just USB on the other end of this cable, so I guess these rules don’t apply here – when I just connect normal USB VCC to my spoofed cable’s target connector VCC, a device connected to it doesn’t charge properly and doesn’t enable USB. Also the set of requests from master on ID line is different. But when I connect with original’s cable VCC (which is limited to 10-15 mA, according to my measurements), the set of requests on ID is exactly same as with original cable. So I guess I need to implement that in the original way